# What's the right way to write Jest tests verified with Flow?

Tags: jestjs, flowtype

I imagine people commonly use Flow and Jest (and React) together, but Flow doesn't seem to know about Jest (or Jasmine) globals. When I add `// @flow` to my tests, I get Flow errors like this:

```
src/__tests__/Thing-test.js:3
  3: jest.unmock('../Thing')
     ^^^^ identifier `jest`. Could not resolve name

src/__tests__/Thing-test.js:7
  7: describe('Thing', () => {
     ^^^^^^^^ identifier `describe`. Could not resolve name

src/__tests__/Thing-test.js:8
  8:   it('does stuff', () => {
       ^^ identifier `it`. Could not resolve name
```

I could write a Flow interface for Jest/Jasmine, but that seems lengthy and like I must be missing something. Letting Flow process `node_modules/jest-cli` doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You can create/install a declaration file for Jest. Either [manually](https://flowtype.org/docs/declarations.html#pointing-your-project-to-declarations) or using [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed): `flow-typed install jest`. Also take a look at this repository where everything is configured: [node-flowtype-boilerplate](https://github.com/jsynowiec/node-flowtype-boilerplate)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Although Jest is written with flow annotations they strip types for the npm version so we don't need babel to run it. Fortunately the types are already in **flow-type** so the solution is quite easy (just as mentioned in the comment):

```
npm install -g flow-typed

flow-typed install jest@22.x.x # <-- replace the version with the latest
```

Although I had to add this line as well to my `.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  "env": {
    "jest": true
  }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  WebStorm still shows a Flow error: identifier 'it'. could not resolve name  
My project was set up with create-react-app.  I don't have file .eslintrc.json

Comment: Make sure you also have `flow-typed` in your `.flowconfig` `[libs]` section as suggested [here](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/458#issuecomment-292932110).

Comment: You don't need to explicitly add `flow-typed` to `.flowconfig`, at least not these days: https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/#toc-what-s-a-library-definition

Comment: i initially didn't notice the `flow-typed install jest@22` line . +1

Comment: You'll likely have no fix until you also `flow stop` and `flow`. the flow cache can cause severe frustration.

Comment: I have a similar problem as @bedouger, already did all the setup (installed plugins, libdefs, set config rules, resetted flow server) with no joy so far. I'll get back here and add proper feedback if I can find a fix.

Answer (score 24):

The accepted answer does not work if you use **Create-React-App**. Here is how you would set up jest with CRA:

**1.Install flow to your project**

If you use create-reat-app, [here](https://flow.org/en/docs/tools/create-react-app/) is a guide for this step.

```
yarn add -D flow-bin
yarn run flow init
```

**2. Install jest flow types**

```
npx flow-typed install jest@22 // maybe you need a different version
```

(You can use `npx jest -v` to check your jest version if you use create-react-app.)

**3. Register flow-typed in config**

*(Update: as @Black points out in the comments, this step may not even be neccessary)*

In your `.flowconfig`, add flow-typed to libs section.

```
...
[libs]
flow-typed
...
```

I use yarn, npm should work just the same.

Comment: `flow-typed` is added by default to `[libs]` section. No need to do that manually https://flow.org/en/docs/config/libs/

Comment: @Black Thanks for pointing that out, I updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: For me only works when I added in `[libs]`. Thanks for this

Answer (score 7):

If you created your project with create-react-app you have to manually add **jest** to your packages.json. Otherwise flow-typed won't install the needed type definitions because create-react-app doesn't add this dependency to packages.json.

```
yarn add --dev jest
flow-typed install
```

Comment: According to Dan Abramov, it is not recommended to install Jest with CRA: *If you have both react-scripts and jest in your package.json things will go badly wrong in the future.* https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5401#issuecomment-378089822

Comment: The above answer assumes that you have `flow-typed` installed globally, via `npm install -g flow-typed`. Alternatively, add it as a project dependency via `yarn add -D flow-typed`, then you can run it `npx flow-typed install`

Answer (score 0):

You can also run it as a one liner.
Here you go:

```sh
npm i -D flow-typed && npx flow-typed install jest@"$(npx jest -v)"
```

Answer (score -1):

I think `declare var jest: any;` should do the trick (put it either on top of each test file, or somewhere in your flow lib directory).