# How to make Flow aware of Jest's globals (test, expect, etc)?

Tags: flowtype, jestjs, flow-typed

I get these Flow errors in my test files:

```
identifier `test`
Could not resolve name

identifier `expect`
Could not resolve name
```

I've installed the Jest libdef from flow-typed but it doesn't make any difference.

---

Update: it looks like the Jest libdef created by flow-typed is just a stub. I think the problem is that flow-typed doesn't have a libdef for Jest v0.21.x yet.

Answer (score 2):

[What's the right way to write Jest tests verified with Flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35898251/whats-the-right-way-to-write-jest-tests-verified-with-flow/40738591)

`flow-typed` now has all versions of Jest:
https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/tree/master/definitions/npm